# What is the way to use the AsyncStorage variable in my situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

What is the proper way to use `AsyncStorage` at following scenario:

I'm try to use `userName` that it's saved in the storage:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const userName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-USERNAME');
```

I just want print the variable "**userName**"

```
export const deleteFromTable = () => {

  console.log('MY ASYNC ================>>>>>>>>>>>', userName);

  fetchUserConnectResponseData().then((result) => {
    console.log('before', JSON.stringify(result));
    deleteUserConnectResponseData().then(() => {
      fetchUserConnectResponseData().then((result1) => {
        console.log('after', JSON.stringify(result1));
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: could you add your full code here? It's seem you are not getting the `userName` on the proper place ( with is inside your deleteFromTable)

Comment: @shira Can you make this `deleteFromTable` an async function and do the await for this inside that  OR you can try using `AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-USERNAME').then(val => {console.log("username:" , val)})`

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, I suppose that you saved data into `AsyncStorage` somewhere like:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('AZURE-USERNAME', 'user name I want to save')
```

Well, you can retrive it in your code in this way:

```
export const deleteFromTable = () => {

  let userName = "";

  AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-USERNAME').then((userName) => {
     console.log('MY ASYNC ================>>>>>>>>>>>', userName);

     fetchUserConnectResponseData().then((result) => {
     console.log('before', JSON.stringify(result));
     deleteUserConnectResponseData().then(() => {
        fetchUserConnectResponseData().then((result1) => {
           console.log('after', JSON.stringify(result1));
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md) through it, you can access the data in AsyncStorage synchronously, making AsyncStorage easier to use.